# Artifactory NuGet Restore

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, artifactory

Is it possible to use an Artifactory NuGet Restore with multiple Repositories(targetResolveRepo) when the Job is built based on the TFS in the classic editor. Same as for the Nuget restore task by pointing to the sln file or NuGet config. When using the Artifactory NuGet Restore task it gives opportunity to choose only one repo from many.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Azure DevOps extension [JFrog Artifactory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension). Judging from the current task page, only one `targetResolveRepo` can be selected.
It is recommended that you can request support or ask the question from the extension developer. You can ask the question [here](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-azure-devops-extension/issues) or [here](https://jfrog.com/support/).

Answer (score 0):

You can select only one resolution repository, but this repository can be a [Virtual repository](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/virtual-repositories) that can aggregate many repositories under it.

Comment: It is definitely good hint. Thank you! But, interesting why if I have one virtual repo(to which I am pointing from the pipeline task) cannot see the Included Repositories which also have relation with that virtual one...

Comment: Virtual repositories are meant to serve as a single logical endpoint, and the developers don't know what's under the hood or the access rules to the aggregated repositories(Users may have limited access to some resources based on their associated permission targets). Besides the repository URL, everything inside a virtual repository can change at any time.  Many users create a virtual repository per project/pipeline with the required repositories for the job.